# Theming Nodes & Arrays in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to get two text fields, one title, one body, to display in a stacked manner. The following code works. Currently, when I use

```
print render($content['field_acc_title'][0]);
```

It doesn't format the output using the typical field.tpl.php. Is there a way to render a specific field[id] but have it format the usual way.

```
<?php
  foreach ($field_acc_title as $id => $field_acc_title){
    print '<h3 class="acc_title">';
    print render($content['field_acc_title'][$id]);
    print '<span class="acc_state"></span></h3>';
    print '<div class="acc_body">';
    print render($content['field_acc_body'][$id]);
    print "</div>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`field_view_value`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_value/7):

```
foreach ($field_acc_title as $id => $field_acc_title) {
  print render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_acc_title', $field_acc_title));
}
```

Comment: That still just outputs the content without any container divs. I'd like the output to have the attribute divs etc.